# Any way to fix or ignore warning FS1240 "This type test or downcast will ignore the unit-of-measure" in F#?

Tags: types, f#, units-of-measurement

I have the following code:

```ml
/// Constant for use in comparing floats within the ray tracer
[<Literal>]
let epsilon = 0.00001

/// Compares the two floats to see if they are epsilon away from each other.
/// See the definition of epsilon to see the resolution of the compare.
let compareFloat (x: float<'u>) (y: float<'u>) = abs(float x - float y) <= epsilon

/// Represents a 3D point
[<CustomEquality; NoComparison>]
type Point<[<Measure>] 'u> = { X: float<'u>; Y: float<'u>; Z: float<'u> } with

    /// Overrides the Object.Equals method to provide a custom equality compare for Point records
    override x.Equals object =
        match object with
        | :? Point<'u> as p -> compareFloat x.X p.X &&
                               compareFloat x.Y p.Y &&
                               compareFloat x.Z p.Z
        | _ -> false

    /// Overrides the Object.GetHashCode method, which is recommended when overriding Object.Equals
    override x.GetHashCode () = hash x // Re-use the built-in hash for records
```

This code is valid code, and you can simply put it into an F# script file to test. The snippet `:? Point<'u>` gives the warning:

> FS1240: This type test or downcast will ignore the unit-of-measure ``u`

Of course, in reality, my `Point` type has several more members, mainly consisting of arithmetic operator overloads. However, this is the problem point. I recently extended the type to be able to handle units, but I am not able to find a way to get rid of this type test warning. I am implementing the custom equality because I want to be able to compare two `Point`s, primarily in tests. I understand that units of measure are a compile time thing and are not available at runtime, and as far as I understand, the type test `:?` happens at runtime. Using `:? Point<_>` surprisingly doesn't work, and an error is given if the unit of measure is left off, which also doesn't make a lot of sense given the warning is telling me it is ignored anyway.

1. Is there a way to modify the code to get rid of this warning?
2. If not, is there a better way to implement custom equality?
3. Is this a bug?

Thank you!

Comment: I think this is a legit warning. It's telling you that, since the units don't exist at runtime, and therefore cannot be checked by casting, you may end up with `{ X = 5<inch> ... }.Equals({ X = 5<meter> ... }) = true`. This is of course the result of .NET's legacy type-erased comparison, but here we are. I would suggest implementing your own comparison, without relying on `Object.Equals`

Comment: `Object.Equals` is required to use the testing libraries, such as FsUnit. Using `should equal` with FsUnit won't work properly without an implementation of `Object.Equals`. In this case, I don't particularly care that the units are thrown away in equality tests using `Object.Equals` during tests. I think it makes sense to provide a custom operator for in-code needs (not to be used in tests) of equality of records with units of measure.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is inspired by Fyodor's comment.

You're trying to use a type extension to compare points, but the fact that units of measure are not available at runtime causes a problem. The compiler complains - though only with a warning, so you can suppress that. But now your code looks like it is taking the units of measure into account when checking for equality, which of course it cannot do. (I wonder if maybe that should be an error and not a warning).

Here's one alternative solution, using a custom operator.

```
type Point<[<Measure>] 'u> = { X: float<'u>; Y: float<'u>; Z: float<'u> }

let epsilon = 0.00001
    
let compareFloat (x: float<'u>) (y: float<'u>) = abs(float x - float y) <= epsilon

let (==) p1 p2 =
    // you could check for reference equality here first
    compareFloat p1.X p2.X &&
    compareFloat p1.Y p2.Y &&
    compareFloat p1.Z p2.Z
```

And some sample code

```
[<Measure>]
type human

[<Measure>]
type klingon

let p1 = {X = 0.0<human>; Y = 1.0<human>; Z = 2.0<human> }
let p2 = {X = 0.0<human>; Y = 1.0<human>; Z = 2.000005<human> }
let p3 = {X = 1.0<human>; Y = 1.0<human>; Z = 2.5<human> }
let p4 = {X = 0.0<klingon>; Y = 1.0<klingon>; Z = 2.0<klingon> }
// won't compile
let p5 = {X = 0.0<human>; Y = 1.0<klingon>; Z = 2.0<klingon> }


// false, uses default equality
p1 = p2

// true
p1 == p2

// false
p2 == p3

// won't compile
// error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
//     'Point<human>'    
// but given a
//     'Point<klingon>'    
// The unit of measure 'human' does not match the unit of measure 'klingon'
p3 == p4
```

Comment: I considered defining a custom equality operator. However, this will cause problems when using FsUnit for testing. For example, something `point(3.0, -2.0, 5.0) + vector(-2.0, 3.0, 1.0) |> should equal (point(1.0, 1.0, 6.0))` needs the `CustomEquality` method to be implemented. It wasn't my choice to implement the `Equals` method. It was required for integration into the testing libraries and a type test or downcasting is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't think so, but you can suppress the warning with `#nowarn "1240"`.
2. No, I think what you're doing is reasonable.
3. No, I think it's just a blemish in the way UoM's work in F#. See this [reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/fsharp/comments/byrlry/downcast_warning_with_units_of_measure/).

Comment: (1) I figured `#nowarn` may be required. I wish `#nowarn` could be used at a function or member level though. (2) Thanks. (3) I haven't convinced myself of this one because the fact that `:? Point<_>` still throws the warning, even though `<_>` means I don't care what the type is and means that I can't use it in any way. Maybe not a bug, but maybe an improvement could be made there. `:? Point` throwing an error I suppose makes sense, but it feels weird that I wants me to put the type parameter there and then complains about it. Haha.

Comment: `Point<_>` doesn’t mean that you don’t care what the type is. It means you’re letting the compiler infer the correct type, which in this case can only be `’u`.